# Take long time to send a mail - odoo 8

Tags: email, time, odoo, odoo-8

I am using below code to access an email template and send mail. It works fine except it took long time **(30 to 60 mins)** to send mail after execution of code. I don't know how to solve this issue? Suggest any solution!!Thanks.

**sen_mail.py**

```
@api.multi
def send_email(self,invoice_id):
     invoice_data = self.env['account.invoice'].browse(invoice_id)
     email_template_obj = self.env['email.template']
     template_id = self.env.ref('multi_db.email_template_subscription_invoice', False)
     if template_id:
        values = email_template_obj.generate_email(template_id.id,invoice_id)
        values['subject'] = 'Invoice for AMS registration'
        values['email_to'] = invoice_data.partner_id.email
        values['partner_to'] = invoice_data.partner_id
     mail_obj = self.env['mail.mail']
     msg_id = mail_obj.create(values)
     if msg_id:
         mail_obj.send([msg_id])
     return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got solution.
I have changed `Interval Number` and `Interval Unit` in Settings -> Technical -> Automation -> Scheduled Actions.

Comment: Please, provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Kabir

Yes sure you can increase email frequency to send email faster from outgoing email queue but if you want to send email immediately without waiting then yon also use below code alternatively:

```
@api.multi
def send_email(self,invoice_id):
    invoice_data = self.env['account.invoice'].browse(invoice_id)
    email_template_obj = self.env['email.template']
    template_id = self.env.ref('multi_db.email_template_subscription_invoice', False)
    if template_id:
         template_id.send_mail(invoice_id, force_send=False, raise_exception=False)
    return True
```

This will send email without waiting.

Bests